# Regex find all words exclude spaces and tabs (\n \t etc.)

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get all words from the string. They can include only letters and number. But I completely failed to exclude possible \n, \t etc.

So here is a test string:

`word
one of each
one fish two fish red fish blue fish
car : carpet as java : javascript!!&@$%^&
testing, 1, 2 testing
go Go GO Stop stop
hello\nworld
hello\tworld
hello  world
\t\tIntroductory Course`

I end up with [this solution](https://regex101.com/r/Mm6g9P/3) .

But
`hello\nworld` should be `hello` `world`
`hello\tworld` should be `hello` `world`
`\t\tIntroductory Course` should be `Introductory` `Course`

I had also tried solutions with \w \b and \S but I can't make them work as I want too.

How can I ignore/exclude \n and \t?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the PHP code with a sample string. You must be mistaking string literals for literal strings.

Comment: Did anything help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pure regex:**

```
(?:\\t|\\n)*([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

**PHP (with escaped `\`):**

```
preg_match_all("/(?:\\\\t|\\\\n)*([A-Za-z0-9]+)/", $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Once I tried preg_match_all pattern it appears to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Match only letters and numbers: `\w`. Check [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
preg_match_all("/\w+/", $str, $matches);
```

If you are not acutally meaning tabs and newlines (with ascii code 9 and 10), then you can just remove the substrings `'\n'` and `'\t'` from the string first:

```
preg_match_all("/\w+/", str_replace(['\n', '\r'], ' ', $str), $matches);
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue with tabs and newlines.

Comment: @falnyr Why not? `preg_match_all` searches the whole string (whether it includes tabs and newlines or not).

Comment: It captures the `\t` and `\n` characters as words: https://3v4l.org/F2C45

Comment: @falnyr I assume the OP meant a real tab by `\t` and a real newline by `\n`.

Comment: @falnyr If not, he could just remove \n and \t from the string (`str_replace()`)...

Comment: Or he could just do `str_replace` for the whole thing instead of using regex, right? :D

Comment: Thanks for you answers and comments, I end up with first solution.

Comment: @bomjastik Then your question was wrong. You were not talking about tabs and newlines, but about strings containing two characters: a backslash and a `t` or `n`. These are no tabs and no newlines. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this solution

```
([^\\nt\!\&\@\$]+[a-z0-9]+)
```

Test here: 
https://regex101.com/r/m9e9AH/1

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it doesn't work as I want. It captures all like instead of only words.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have updated the code, try to use this instead `([^\\nt\!\&\@\$^\s]{1}[a-z0-9]+)` I have updated the example in regex link  https://regex101.com/r/m9e9AH/3